# Which is the best use of useEffect to fetch multiple data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm some confused about some different ways to use the `useEffect` hook to fetch API data. I want to know if there is a "best way" to do this, performance related, or if it really doesn't matter how to do it.

Consider the following ways:

**Mutiple function calls to fetch API data inside a single `useEffect`:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    const students = await studentService.getAll()
    setStudents(students)
  }

  const fetchCourses = async () => {
    const courses = await courseService.getAll()
    setCourses(courses)
  }

  const fetchSchedules = async () => {
    const schedules = await scheduleService.getAll()
    setSchedules(schedules)
  }


  fetchStudents()
  fetchCourses()
  fetchSchedules()
}, [])
```

**A single function call to fetch all the api data inside a single `useEffect`:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAllData = async () => {
    const students = await studentService.getAll()
    const courses = await courseService.getAll()
    const schedules= await scheduleService.getAll()

    setStudents(students)
    setCourses(courses)
    setSchedules(schedules)
  }

  fetchAllData()
}, [])
```

**Maybe, multiple `useEffect`s for each api call:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchStudents= async () => {
    const students = await studentService.getAll()

    setStudents(students)
  }

  fetchStudents()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCourses = async () => {
    const courses = await courseService.getAll()

    setCourses(courses)
  }

  fetchCourses()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchSchedules = async () => {
    const schedules= await scheduleService.getAll()

    setSchedules(schedules)
  }

  fetchSchedules()
}, [])
```

Is there another way to consider? Let it be known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example you wait for each promise to resolve before executing the next one, this will hurt performance, the other examples are all running in parallel.

I would go with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) inside a single `useEffect` because i think its more readable then 3 `useEffect` or 3 functions, and this will also make sure all of our promises are executing in parallel.

Note that if one of the promises inside `Promise.all` reject, the function is going to throw and you won't have any access to the resolved promises

```
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all([
    studentService.getAll().then(setStudents),
    courseService.getAll().then(setCourses),
    scheduleService.getAll().then(schedules)
  ])
}, [])
```